A C# Windows Forms application (.NET Framework 4.5.2) suddenly closes
A C# Windows Forms application (.NET Framework 4.5.2) suddenly closes on a client's system, but it works properly on my system and other client systems, and exception tracking is not working.
"The Event Viewer is showing an error as follows:
Faulting application name: Beneficio.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x67595e22
Faulting module name: shell32.dll, version: 10.0.22000.2482, timestamp: 0x54c43e90
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00158450
Faulting process ID: 0x2558
Faulting application start time: 0x01db4bbc6e0f84c1
Faulting application path: D:\Beneficio\Beneficio.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll
Report ID: 7a4e4935-3f79-4a0e-886e-b9a1c13150f4
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:"
Edited:
The client’s system is running on Windows 11.

Please [edit] your question and provide some additional information. What version of Windows is running on the system? What external libraries does the application require? Are those libraries installed on the system. The application is not even running to generate a .NET exception. Can other .NET applications run on the system?

Please [edit] provide the required information I asked. The application is crashing before the form is even drawn, which suggests, a library it requires does exist on the system. So what differences on the two client machines is there?

Do the crash logs let you see what other modules have been loaded into the process? Anything that touches the Windows GUI shell has some risk of having all the third-party "shell extension" DLLs loaded into it.
